# Code does not run while using MongoDB change stream

Tags: python, mongodb, discord.py, changestream

I have been building a Discord bot, which will send messages to selected channels in servers on a change in the database, specifically if a new document is inserted. I am using MongoDB as the database, I came to know about collection.watch() in pymongo. I wrote the code for watch() in db.py as given in the pymongo documentation.
"hackathons" here is the collection on which the watch method is applied.

```
def new_hackathon():
    try:
        resume_token = None
        pipeline = [{'$match':{'operationType':'insert'}}]
        with hackathons.watch(pipeline) as stream:
            for change in stream:
                print(change)
                resume_token = stream.resume_token
    except pymongo.errors.PyMongoError:
        if resume_token is None:
            logging.error('...')
        else:
            with hackathons.watch(pipeline, resume_after=resume_token) as stream:
                for change in stream:
                    print(change)
```

I have called the new_hackathon() function in another file.

```
class Channels(commands.Cog):
    #class methods
    new_hackathon()

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Channels(bot))
```

The call to new_hackathon() function does not lets the cog load, thus no response is given by the bot. If the function is not called the bot works perfectly.

Comment: Is your MongoDB configured as a replicaset?

Comment: I am using MongoDB Atlas, and the type there states as a replica set - 3 nodes.

Comment: You've got a lot of extraneous stuff in your code that isn't relevant to the issue. Could I suggest you try and isolate it down to the bare minimum set of code focusing just on the watch component. Also I notice that the call to `new_hackathon()` sits in the class not in a particular function in the class. Is that your intention?

Comment: Sorry for the extraneous stuff. Just cleaned it. Yes, the call to the function is in the class as I wanted to invoke it as soon as the bot is loaded and the collection watch is started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the good news is that I ran your code and I can see the change streams coming through. So that's a good start.

I would therefore get you to double check the connection string, database and collection parameters are all set correctly.

One of the issues with change streams is that if you have these configured incorrectly it will happily just sit there doing nothing ...

Comment: The code for change stream does work for me when a document is inserted, but the cogs do not get loaded. It seems the interpreter is stuck inside the `new_hackathon()` method. Thus, the `add_cog` method doesn't get completed.

Comment: You understand that the watch process is a blocking process? You can't do anything else while the watch is running unless you start it asynchronously.

Comment: Okay, didn't know it was a blocking process. I Will try and work around asynchronously

Comment: I got away around without using change stream, just used a cache to save previous data and created a scheduler to periodically check for changes, send the message and store it in the cache.